# What is non_field_errors?

Tags: python, django, forms

I use forms.Form and forms.ModelForm

```
{% if form.non_field_errors %}
        {% for err in form.non_field_errors %}
            <span style="color:darkred;">{{ err }}</span><br />
        {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
```

> Show nothing

```
{{ form.errors }}
```

> Show everything,clean_fields() and form.

Answer (score 0):

`form.non_field_errors` is for errors related to the entire form as such. Basically, errors which are not related to any particular field in the form.
This could be any custom validation errors that you raise in the form clean logic, etc.

`form.errors` is for all errors (field as well as non field)
Since there are not non_field_errors, it shows nothing.
To show field errors, you have to use `field.errors` for each field in the form

Comment: forms.Form does clean_field but form.non_field_errors still none...

Comment: Can you explain your comment further? I didn't quite understand it

Comment: Did you get this solved?

Comment: No,I did not get.

Comment: Do you want to chat and find a solution? here is the [link](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254112/room-for-arun-t-and-aaaa)

Comment: Never mind.....